# Test data being used for validation data in keras fit_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I use keras(tensorflow) to train my model. I use the function `fit_generator` cause I use `ImageDataGenerator` to make data augmentation.

Here's my question,I find there's two kind of training process.The former I don't know what it is, but the later is just the model is learning from the original data.And the situation is below:

```
...

    145/147 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.5847 - acc: 0.5120
    146/147 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.5838 - acc: 0.5117
...
```

it seems that this epoch will end ,but then a new training start in this epoch.

```
...
     32/1567 [..............................] - ETA: 3:11 - loss: 1.8080 - acc: 0.4688
     64/1567 [>.............................] - ETA: 2:58 - loss: 1.7491 - acc: 0.5000
...
```

Besides I post relating code right here

```
datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator( featurewise_std_normalization=True, rotation_range=20,
                                 width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)
datagen.fit(trainX)
model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE),
                            steps_per_epoch=trainX.shape[0]//BATCH_SIZE, epochs=10,
                            validation_data=(testX,testY),
                            verbose=1,callbacks=[tb_cb,reduce_lr,early])
```

Did I do some thing wrong? And I don't find any solution

Relly hopeing that someone can help me ,thank you

--------------------------------Updata---------------------------------

At first I thought it's `steps_per_epoch`'s fault.But I am wrong. When I restart the training without `steps_per_epoch`. It shows again.

By elimination, I found it is caused by `validation_data`.I don't know why,and I can't delete `validation_data` cause it must be used if I use `tensorboard` in the callbacks. And I find it will process so fast if I delete the function of tensorboard and leave the validation_data.

here's my tensorboard function in callbacks:

```
 tb_cb = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=board_file, write_images=1, histogram_freq=1)
```

There must be some relationship between `keras.callbacks.TensorBoard` and `validation_data`

In addition, as the api for `validation_steps` says：

> Only relevant if `validation_data`
>               is a generator. Total number of steps (batches of samples)
>               to yield from `generator` before stopping.
>               Optional for `Sequence`: if unspecified, will use
>               the `len(validation_data)` as a number of steps.

And I can tell that the steps of new training process actually equals to the number of my validation data.

Comment: Try dropping the `steps_per_epoch` argument

Comment: It seems works.But why shouldn't I set the `steps_per_epoch`? As the official api says  **Total number of steps (batches of samples)** and **It should typically be equal to the number of samples of your dataset divided by the batch size.**

Comment: Check the answer I wrote. Let me know if you need any additional help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fit_generator` also create a validation data generator.So it's validation process is also divided in batchs, and what I see after training  is just the intermediate result。And model won't train on the validation data.

here's some relative discussion about that:

[Test data being used for validation data?](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1753)

[Test data being used for validation data in chinese](https://www.jianshu.com/p/0c7af5fbcf72)